# Vim <alt+X> bindings don't work in terminal

Tags: vim, terminal

I've a mapping `nmap <A-k> :wincmd k<CR>` which works in gui vim, but not in terminal. How to make this mapping work in terminal mode?

Comment: What terminal are you running Vim in?  It may be consuming the key press.

Answer (score 4):

Many terminals don't "get" the `Alt` key and have to be configured for it to work and Vim has some longstanding issues of its own with the `Alt` key.

My advice is to use mappings that work everywhere: GUI and CLI. `<leader>` is perfect for that, see `:help leader`.

```
nnoremap <leader>k :wincmd k<CR>
```